# Where is the keyboard layout file for "French (legacy, alternative)"?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm just getting started with Linux and wanted to modify my keyboard layout. Following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A+Custom+keyboard+layout+definitions) tutorial, I went into `usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and looked for a file called `fr`. But when I opened it up, I found something that doesn't seem to correspond to my keyboard layout. For example, it has this entry:

```
key <AD01>  { [         a,          A,           ae,           AE ] };
```

But when I press AltGr + A, I don't get anything like an "ae" symbol, I get "â". Other entries in the file don't match what I get when I type either.

Now, when I click on the keyboard layout button up top, I find that my layout isn't "French", it's "French (legacy, alternative)". Is that connected to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question in the title is: It's in the same file as the basic French layout. In the version of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` I have installed, the definitions for "French (legacy, alternative)" begins on line 339.

Before modifying the layout, you need to decide on which layout your modified layout should be based.